# php script downloads after form submission instead of execution

Tags: php, pdf, filesize

The site have a form where pdf is uploaded and form is submitted. For small pdf file size 345KB. it works fine. But for large pdf size the php script ids downloaded instead of execution. I have chnaged the .htaccess as per below for large file support. But for large files same happens.

.htaccess -

php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value max_execution_time 3600
php_value max_input_time 3600
php_value memory_limit 32M

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Mangesh

Answer (score 0):

Even if a php file fails to run, it should NEVER be downloaded (I assume the downloaded script shows all your php code). This is a serious (apache) problem. Contact your webhost with this!

Comment: Is the actual script being downloaded, or is it a blank file named yourscript.php, or yourscript.php with some output of your php script? If you're getting a blank file named yourscript.php or one that contains your HTML output, Apache something is going wrong with the headers, probably due to incomplete execution of your script.

You should also check with your webhost and see if they allow override of php.ini values in .htaccess files, or if you have to use another method, like creating a local php.ini, or if they allow overrides at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  can this be solved with .htaccess modification etc? if yes then what modifications will need as the form submision for lesser pdf upload works find. The above issue is with l;arge pdfs only. Please suggest.

Comment: first of all you should find out what's the cause the script is offered back as download... What's the exact response? (use the developer tools in Chrome to check the response and headers, this is very helpfull!)